# Stack Exchange currently offline - but only when running stack snippets

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

I am getting the following message when clicking "run snippet"

## Stack Exchange is currently offline, we'll be back shortly!

[image]

**UPDATE**: Seems the site http://stacksnippets.net/ is down (for maintenance)

Comment: Cross-site dup of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263354/after-the-move-to-denver-stacksnippets-net-is-offline

Comment: I really tried to find a duplicate - I did not guess it would be due to another site's issue

Comment: this is [tag:status-completed]

Comment: Do I delete this then?

Comment: @mplungjan Cross site dups are fine in cases like this. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240568/can-bug-reports-and-feature-requests-requiring-se-dev-attention-be-reported-on-p , but preferably when bug affecting all sites report on meta.SE. When bug only affects one site than report on that site's meta. ----- No need to delete your question (I sure wouldn't with 14 score!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) :

> That's a bug. We'll investigate.
>
> Update: I see the problem. Working on it
>
> Update: Fixed. Thank @nick-craver for doing the heavy lifting!
>
> ~ by [Tom Limoncelli](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/222882/tom-limoncelli), [src](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263369/244519)